# Paypal issue at checkout page

Tags: payment-methods, paypal, payment, paypal-express

I have got on one page checkout page---> Fatal error: Call to a member function setConfigObject() on a non-object in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Pro.php on line 135.

Please solve this issue.